# Using counter values as part of style name for plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, counters, tikz-styles

I figured I should be able to give a bunch of line styles and access them using counters. Sure enough, this works out fine; this document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\tikzset{%
  Line 1/.style={color=blue,dashdotted},
  Line 2/.style={color=red,densely dashed},
  Line 3/.style={color=black,densely dotted}
}

\newcounter{counter}
\newenvironment{test}{%
  \setcounter{counter}{1} 
  \begin{tikzpicture}
}{%
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\tester}{%
  \draw[style=Line \thecounter] (\thecounter,0) -- (\thecounter,1);
  \stepcounter{counter}
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{test}
    \tester
    \tester
  \end{test}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image: works]

as expected. However, if I change the environment and command definition to do some plotting, i.e.

```
\newenvironment{test}{%
  \setcounter{counter}{1} 
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
}{%
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

and

```
\newcommand{\tester}{%
  \addplot[style=Line \thecounter,id=plot_\thecounter] function{\thecounter + x*\thecounter};
  \stepcounter{counter}
}
```

I get this:

[image: works not]

Clearly, the *third* style is used for both plots; it seems to use the counter value *after* all `\tester` commands (i.e. at the end of `axis`). Note how all other instances of `\thecounter` are expanded as expected.

What is going on here, and how do I fix it?

<sup>I think you can have `pgfplots` rotate through styles; I would like to start with the first style in every plot, though.</sup>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PGFplots way to achieve this is to define a `plot cycle list` using

```
\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{<name>}{
<first style options>\\%
<second style options>\\%
...\\%
}`
```

The cycle list will start again for every new axis. If you want to use a manually defined style for one of your plots without advancing the `plot cycle list` counter, you can call `\pgfplotsset{step cycle list=-1}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{raphaelslist}{
  blue, dashdotted\\%
  red, densely dashed\\%
  black,densely dotted\\%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[cycle list name=raphaelslist]
    \addplot function {1+x};
    \addplot [orange, ultra thick] {2+2*x};
    \pgfplotsset{cycle list shift=-1}
    \addplot function {3+3*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

---

If you want to stick with your homebrew counter solution, you'll have to expand the counter using an `\edef` in your plot command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\tikzset{%
  Line 1/.style={color=blue,dashdotted},
  Line 2/.style={color=red,densely dashed},
  Line 3/.style={color=black,densely dotted}
}

\newcounter{counter}

\newenvironment{test}{%
  \setcounter{counter}{1} 
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
}{%
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
}


\newcommand{\tester}{%
  \edef\doplot{
    \noexpand\addplot[style=Line \thecounter,id=plot_\thecounter] function{\thecounter + x*\thecounter};
  }
  \doplot
  \stepcounter{counter}
}


\begin{document}
  \begin{test}
    \tester
    \tester
  \end{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So it *does* start from the first for every axis. Thanks! Any leads on the counter issue, though? Cycle lists may not always be as flexible as needed (e.g. rotate some lines though the list but have fixed styles for others).

Comment: @Raphael: Cycle lists are surprisingly flexible. I've edited my answer to show how to use the counter approach, though.

Comment: I see, thank you. In this case, homebrew is certainly not preferred.

Comment: +1 is it worth mentioning `\addplot+...`