# Access cycle list entries by name or number, not with cycle list shift

Tags: pgfplots

`pgfplots` offers the convenient feature of `cycle list` which helps a lot to keep consistent line styles throughout several plots. However, I have typically different line styles (assume some kind of repeating underlying data or equations) which appear rather randomly. Accessing the suitable entry of the `cycle list` with `cycle list shift` is rather cumbersome and requires manual changes if I add or remove curves in the plot.

I have made a simple example. The first plot contains polynomials from linear to fifth order, the second one only the odd ones (i.e., an arbitrary subset of the first curves plot).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
% First axis, three types of plots
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
domain=-1:1,legend entries={1,...,5},legend pos=south east,
cycle list name=exotic,
]
\addplot {x};
\addplot {x^2};
\addplot {x^3};
\addplot {x^4};
\addplot {x^5};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

% Second axis, only some type of plots (here: only odd polynomials)
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
domain=-1:1,legend entries={1,3,5},legend pos=south east,
cycle list name=exotic,
]
\addplot {x};
\pgfplotsset{cycle list shift=1}
\addplot {x^3};
\pgfplotsset{cycle list shift=2}
\addplot {x^5};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Exemplary output, the choice of the cycle list is arbitrary:

[image]

The consistent line styles are here achieved by manipulating the `cycle list shift` number. I would prefer a solution with an option in the style of `\addplot[cycle list entry=1]` or even with a custom label `\addplot[cycle list entry=linear]`. My question is, can this be done in `pgfplots`?

The only way I can think of to achieve the desired behavior is a manual one, i.e., [defining a macro containing the desired plot options](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64237/44467) as

```
\pgfplotsset{%
  apply style/.code={%
    \tikzset{#1}%
  }
}
\def\linear{blue, dashed}
```

Then, the plot can be added as

```
\addplot[apply style/.expand once=\linear] {x};
```

I could not find this kind of feature in the `pgfplots` manual, but I assume it could be useful to many users.

Comment: related question/answer which sets the cycle list counter to a fixed value: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50874/using-counter-values-as-part-of-style-name-for-plots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I found so far is not related to cycle lists, but works with defining custom `tikz` styles. It still could be enhanced if the style is defined by accessing the nth entry of a cycle list, but I do not know how to achieve this.

Defining custom styles:

```
\tikzset{
  general/.style  = {thick,mark options={solid}},
  linear/.style   = {general,green,mark=+},
  quadratic/.style= {general,red,mark=x,},
  cubic/.style    = {general,blue,dashed,mark=square},
%...
}
```

Using them:

```
\addplot[style=linear] {x};
\addplot[style=cubic] {x^3};
\addplot[style=quintic] {x^5};
```

instead of the relevant part of the question, i.e., instead of

```
\addplot {x};
\pgfplotsset{cycle list shift=1}
\addplot {x^3};
\pgfplotsset{cycle list shift=2}
\addplot {x^5};
```